# Task.WhenAll.Partitioner.Create().GetPartitions(2).Select() show three ThreadId

Tags: c#, task

Task.WhenAll.Partitioner.Create().GetPartitions(2).Select() show three ThreadId

Demo Code:

```
async Task Execute()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(Partitioner.Create(new[] { "L1", "L2","L3","L4","L5" }.ToList(), false).GetPartitions(2).Select(url =>
       Task.Run(async() =>
       {
           while (url.MoveNext())
           {
               await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);
               Console.WriteLine($"{url.Current} | ThreadId:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
           }
       }
   )));
}
```

And Found that sometimes more than 2 threads, like:

```
L4 | ThreadId:32
L1 | ThreadId:33
L2 | ThreadId:33
L5 | ThreadId:19
L3 | ThreadId:33
```

[image]

I expect just `two thread` to use, I would appreciate it if someone give me some ideas, thanks!

My goal:
I want to control the number of threads

Comment: Why do you expect that and why do you care? There's no reason to use code like that. If you want to process a lot of data, use `Parallel.ForEach` with the DOP you want. If you want to perform a lot of IO cooncurrently, use `ActionBlock` with a DOP

Comment: In any case, `await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);` means execution can continue on any available thread, the runtime has no obligation to go back to the original synchronization context (eg the UI thread). This means the rest of the code will probably run on the same thread that handled the timer behind `Task.Delay`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I hope control the number of thread.

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. They're a *promise* that something will produce something at some point in the *future*.  In other languages, eg C++ or JavaScript, actually use the terms `promise`. Those promises may or may NOT execute on a thread. Async IO operations don't use threads

Comment: The structure that performs async operations easily and controls the number of concurrent operations is `ActionBlock< T>`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, I am confused them, can you answer below, I want to mark it as the best answer.